# Determine originating exchange from RabbitMQ Message

Tags: rabbitmq

I have several exchanges that are dumping messages into a single queue for consumption by a client app. When the messages are received, I'd like to be able to see the exchange the message was originally published to so I can add some metadata to the object. Is there anything I can look at in the message properties that can tell me where it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AMQP 0-9-1` specifications include the name of the exchange the message was published to in the [`basic.get_ok`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.get-ok) answer of the [`basic.get`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.get) method.

Therefore, you should be able to retrieve such information. It just depends on the client you are using and to what degree it honors the `AMQP` specifications.